# Visual studio 2019 c++ support of concepts - compiles successfully with error: Why?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++-concepts

I have installed the latest version of visual studio to test concepts. I try e.g.:

```
struct One{};
struct Two{
    std::string ToString() const
    {
        return "BAM!";
    }
};

template<typename T>
concept hasToString = requires(T t) { t.ToString(); };

template <class T>
void DoString(T& t)
{
    if constexpr (hasToString<T>)
    {
        std::cout << t.ToString() << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
       std::cout << "not available" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    One one{};
    Two two{};
    DoString(one);
    DoString(two);
    return 0;
}
```

This compiles (with /std::c++latest), and gives the output I expected:

```
not available
BAM!
```

However, visual studio community c++ 16.5.0 gives 1 error (even though it completes compilation):

identifier "concept" is undefined

I have no clue why? According to below post, concepts should be supported.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/c20-concepts-are-here-in-visual-studio-2019-version-16-3/

So am I doing something wrong? What? Or is this bug, and if so, is there a way to suppress the error until MS fixes the bug?

Comment: What do you mean by "gives 1 error"? *What* is giving you the error? The compiler?

Comment: It is in the error list below

Comment: I have not used compilers that accept such modern thins. However, [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) there's an example where they include `#include <concepts>`. Might it be this?

Comment: @willem: Error list below *what*?

Comment: So in the visual studio screen, there is an error list when you compile. That gives this error..

Comment: Oh my: now I get it. This is the intellisense generating the error. That sort of explains. I didn't know intellisense generates its errors independently of the compiler..

Comment: @willem: Can you copy&paste this error list?

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error (active) E0020 identifier "concept" is undefined <project name> C:\...\main.cpp 507

Comment: I have visual studio community 16.4.5 and, if I enable the compiler option /std:c++latest, this code compiles (obviously I have to include `#include <iostream>`). I don't understand why you differentiate between community and non-community visual studio.

Comment: @apalomer does your intellisense generate an error?

Comment: Not at compile time. But I see the keyword `concept` underlined as an error (with the text that you already mentioned).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are describing an error coming from *Intellisense*, the engine that does red squiggly lines in the code editor as you type (and populates a "live" error list as you develop).

Though this is compiling your code, it's actually using a different engine from the one that's actually building your project and producing an executable.

According to [the feature announcement you linked to](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/c20-concepts-are-here-in-visual-studio-2019-version-16-3/), it's not quite up-to-date yet (not outrageous for a brand new feature):

> IntelliSense support is not currently available

Ignore.

Comment: That would make a lot of sense. I have compiled it without a problem but I do have the `concept` keyword underlined in the editor.

Comment: Unfortunately this sort of thing we just have to live with.