# Visual Studio Community 2022 Identifier concept is undefined

Tags: c++, concept

I'm a beginner with C++ and VisualStudio Community 2022(v17.4.3) and started to familiarize myself with `concept` feature but got into trouble with build.
I'm trying to run this code but build is failed with message `Identifier 'concept' is undefined`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <concepts>

template<typename T>
concept C1 = sizeof(T) != sizeof(int);

int main()
{
    std::cout << __cplusplus << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

If I remove the `concept` and run it, this is the output(**See update below**):
[image]

I also found these topics, but neither helped me.

[Visual Studio for C++ - identifier "concept" is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60695733/visual-studio-for-c-identifier-concept-is-undefined)

[visual studio 2019 c++ - concept identifier is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59379735/visual-studio-2019-c-concept-identifier-is-undefined)

[Undefined identifier "concept" in Visual Studio 2022](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73994597/undefined-identifier-concept-in-visual-studio-2022)

[Visual studio 2019 c++ support of concepts - compiles successfully with error: Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60777210/visual-studio-2019-c-support-of-concepts-compiles-successfully-with-error-w)

Looks like Intellisence is not available for me because it is community version.(so this would be not the root cause).
Project Language configurations also look right. See the screenshot below.
[image]

I would be really appreciated for any help with this.

**Update(one inaccuracy)**
If I remove `concept` code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <concepts>

//template<typename T>
//concept C1 = sizeof(T) != sizeof(int);

int main()
{
    std::cout << __cplusplus << "Hello World!\n";
    std::cout << _MSC_VER << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

I'm getting this
[image]

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74009551/97248

Comment: @pts ok, I did this in Configuration Properties -> General, like it is on the screenshot from that post, but it doesn't help(

Comment: I do not see anything wrong in your code or configuration. Are you sure the dialog you are showing is for the same project and build configuration that you are trying to build and run? Is the file you are trying to compile a `.cpp`? The error means that you are compiling for C++17 or earlier. (Checking `__cplusplus` doesn't help, because MSVC always sets it to C++98.)

Comment: The dialog box says "Active(Debug)" and "Win32". This means that you change the settings for 32-bit, but presumably then compile for 64-bit.

Comment: @user17732522 In MSVC, there's a special [`/Zc:__cplusplus`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-cplusplus?view=msvc-170) option for that.

Comment: Also, if this is just for learning, I would try latest version 17.5.4 rather than 17.4.3 from last year.

Comment: @Bop, I've updated it either, but it didn't help. The issue was in chosen options Configuration and Platform. See my response below. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to solve this issue. Thank you all for the ideas. The solution below.

I am running the project with `Configuration: Debug and Platform: x64`

But when I opened `Right Click on Project -> Properties , etc.` I didn't notice that it was opened with different configuration and platform. So in my case I just changed Configuration and Platform to the ones I'm working on, changed `C++ Language Standard`to the latest, clicked Ok and it started to work.
[image]